# How to create new button runtime

Tags: vb.net, button, runtime

i use this code in vb to add a new button on runtime:

```
Sub AddButton(ByVal label As String, ByVal location As Point)

Dim b As Button

b = New Button
b.Location = location
b.Text = label
Me.Controls.Add(b)

End Sub
```

but i want to give it a name and get/set its properties and also give it new event
such as give it a click event , that change the text of my new button.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You name the button like this:

```
Sub AddButton(ByVal label As String, ByVal location As Point)
    '...
    b.Name = "MyButton"
    '...
End Sub
```

And you add a click handle like this:

```
Sub AddButton(ByVal label As String, ByVal location As Point)
    '...
    'Option 1:
    AddHandler b.Click, Sub(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) CType(sender, Button).Text = "NewText"

    'Option 2:
    AddHandler b.Click, AddressOf MyButtonClick
    '...
End Sub

Private Sub MyButtonClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    CType(sender, Button).Text = "NewText"
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you a lot for your helpful answer. but just a thing left. the number of new buttons is unknown and user can creates as he needs. but i want to handle different event for each of new button. i define my b as new array. now i want to give special click event to each of b items.